# How to remove duplicates per row and loop by column in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a set of data that is categorised by months every 3 columns. In other words, e.g. columns A to C is September, columns D to F is October and so on. I would like help on removing duplicates in each row for each month, so that if data in one row in columns A and B and C matches another row, the duplicate cells in that row is deleted. This is then repeated for the next month (next 3 columns D, E and F).

So far I've only managed to find scripts that remove duplicate rows in a specific range but not how to remove duplicate cells in rows and loop every few columns.

This is the code I have so far for removing duplicate rows in a specific range:

```
function deleteDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = "Master";
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(source);
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(3, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 3)
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  var keepData = new Array();
  var deleteCount = 0;

  for(i in sourceData) { 
     var row = sourceData[i];
     var duplicate = false; 
        for(j in keepData) { 
           if(row[0] == keepData[j][0] && 
              row[1] == keepData[j][1] && 
              row[2] == keepData[j][2]) { 
              duplicate = true;  
           }
        }
     if(!duplicate) { 
     keepData.push(row); 
     } 
   }

  sourceRange.clear();
  sourceSheet.getRange(3, 1, keepData.length, 
  keepData[0].length).setValues(keepData);

}
```

I'm pretty new to scripting so any help with modifying this script or new inputs is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Update: Here's an example data in my google sheets if it makes it clearer.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IDcBlzFj6992RvMXS3TOyqaS5HsSRqjxk5HXsnYrGkA/

Comment: Yes, it will be rather unlikely you ever find a script you can simply drop in and use. Try writing a function that, given an arbitrary-length array, returns an array of sub-arrays. E.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` becomes `[ [1, 2, 3], [4, , ] ]`. Then try to work that function into your script, to extract months from rows. There are many ways to approach this, so your question is too broad to be answerable currently.

Comment: `duplicate row is deleted.`  How? A row would include D to F and all other columns right. Delete row3, just because A3:C3 is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

There's probably a lot of easier ways to do it.  But I liked the problem so here's a way to do it.  This example generates is own random data so you need to take that out before running it on your dataset. But if I pasted it correctly and you copy it correctly and make a Sheet2 for it to work on then it should run okay for you.  If not, please be prepared to debug it on your own.

By the way it also has some extraneous notes and result so that I could figure out if it was working or not.  Good Luck.  Also I haven't tried it but I don't think this cares if the months appear in consecutive columns.

```
  function removeDupesInGroups(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  generateContent(3,1,100,9);
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),9);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var hdr={};
  var dA=[];
  for(var j=0;j<vA[0].length;j++){
    if(!hdr.hasOwnProperty(vA[0][j])){
      hdr[vA[0][j]]=[];
      hdr[vA[0][j]].push(j);
    }else{
      hdr[vA[0][j]].push(j);
    }
  }
  var n=0;
  for(key in hdr){
    var m=key;
    var uA=[];
    for(var i=2;i<vA.length;i++){
      var tA=[];
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
        var elements=hdr[key].join(',');
        if(hdr[key].indexOf(j)>-1){
          tA.push(vA[i][j]);
        }   
      }
      if(i<vA.length){
        if(!isArrayContained(uA,tA)){
          uA.push(tA);
        }else{
          sh.deleteRow(i - n + 1);
          dA.push([Utilities.formatString('n=%s,i=%s,deleeting row %s,key=%s,group=%s',n,i,i-n+1,key,tA.join('|'))]);
          sh.getRange(1, 10).setValue(Utilities.formatString('n=%s,i=%s,deleeting row %s,group=%s',n,i,i-n+1,tA.join(',')));
          n++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var resultrg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+2,1,dA.length,1).setValues(dA);
}

function isArrayContained(c,t){
  for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
    var isEqual=true;
    for(var j=0;j<c[i].length;j++){
      var t1=c[i][j];
      var t2=t[j];
      if(c[i][j]!=t[j]){
        isEqual=false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(isEqual){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function generateContent(row,col,rows,cols){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh.getDataRange().clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1,1,2,9).setValues([['Jan','Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb','Feb','Mar','Mar','Mar'],['Header','Header','Header','Header','Header','Header','Header','Header','Header']])
  var rg=sh.getRange(row,col,rows,cols);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var s="For the Lamb on the Throne will be their Shepard.";
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
      vA[i][j]=s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length+1));
    } 
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient, but I tried this amendment to my code and it works for my purposes with test data. Here's the final code I used.

```
function deleteDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = "Master";
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(source);

 for (var a=1; a<=19; a+=3){
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(3, a, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 3)
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  var keepData = new Array();
  var deleteCount = 0;

    for(i in sourceData) { 
    var row = sourceData[i];
    var duplicate = false; 
      for(j in keepData) { 
        if(row[0] == keepData[j][0] && 
          row[1] == keepData[j][1] && 
          row[2] == keepData[j][2]) { 
          duplicate = true;  
       }
      }
    if(!duplicate) { 
    keepData.push(row); 
    } 
  }

  sourceRange.clear();
  sourceSheet.getRange(3, a, keepData.length, 
  keepData[0].length).setValues(keepData);

}
```

It basically starts at column a and adds 3 to it which changes the source range and loops until it reaches column 19.